# What does data go when the disk is full?

Tags: operating-system

I know the data go to the disk when RAM is full.  Where do the data go when the disk is full?  How will the operating system handle this case?

Comment: Into the bit bucket at the back of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, sometimes, you may be subject to data corruption. For example, as your computer crashes due to insufficient free space, if some of your files are still opened at that time, the file may become compromised, such as damaged PST.[enter link description here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/will-happen-hard-drive-full/)